# end the Password and Username from Angular to the IdentityServer without redirecting

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a working Angular APP with IdentityServer4, and when I want to login, I am redirected to the idsrv4 and I login there, and I am redirected to my Angular App.

Is it possible just to send the Username and Password to the idsrv4 without redirecting?

If it is possible, how do I create the call from Angular?

Comment: It is possible but not recommended using client credentials flow.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Can you please elaborate in how is possible? how can I build that call? My Grand Type is Implicit. Thanks.

Comment: This is not possibe with implicit flow. The user has to login on the IdentityServer website in order to prevent interception of the credentials.

Comment: If you do that you might as well not use IdentityServer4, as one of its key objectives is that the client application has no visibility of user credentials. If you’re trying to authenticate a non-user; e.g. an application, it supports that (using client-credentials flow)..

Comment: that kinda defeats the purpose of the token server. Imagine you went to login to a website, and you clicked login through google, Instead of redirecting you to google, they just asked for you email and password, would you want to trust that website?

Comment: Thanks guys, all of you have an excellent point.

Comment: Since you are the owner of both the app and the Identity Server ROPC flow is fine, we also have an angular app and use IS for auth (both hosted on same domain and using ssl). No need for redirects (implicit flow), just send the username/password, better UX imho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the comments say - this is not recommended for various reasons.

https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

...but totally doable from a protocol point of view

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3

some samples:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/JavaScriptResourceOwner/index.html#L44-L63

Comment: Thanks, I will be checking today everything. Last year I implemented Identityserver4 for a .Net Core MVC, which was really easy, but for Angular I am following an example in Pluralsight which is good, but my boss wanted to make it in a different way and I didn't have an answer for it.